# HighMap data label is shown rotated

Tags: highcharts, justpy

I tried to display some map results in JustPy, but HighMap data labels in JustPy show as rotated, but only the label is roated not the map itself.

```py
import justpy as jp

my_chart_def = """
{
 chart: {
    map: 'custom/europe',
    borderWidth: 1
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Nordic countries'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Demo of drawing all areas in the map, only highlighting partial data'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Country',
    data: [
      ['is', 1],
      ['no', 1],
      ['se', 1],
      ['dk', 1],
      ['fi', 1]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        },
    }]
}
"""

def chart_test():
    wp = jp.WebPage()
    wp.head_html = """
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/9.2.2/highmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/europe.js"></script>
    """
    my_chart = jp.HighCharts(a=wp, classes='m-2 p-2 border w-1/2 h-screen', options=my_chart_def)
    my_chart.options.chart.type = 'map'
    my_chart.options.series[0].name = 'Test chart'
    my_chart.options.title.text = 'Data'
    return wp

jp.justpy(chart_test)
```

This is what I got: [image: Map1]

If I rotate the map 90 degrees, this is what I see, and the label seems aligned [image: Rotated]

Comment: I see this is based on  https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyJustpyWidgets/blob/main/jpdemo/examples/highchartmap_demo.py where the issue is the version of the map. What's the problem with the rotation?

Comment: The original map without rotations is not aligned with the data label. Your demo also shows this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced your example in the editor, and everything seems to be correct https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6g92m7br/, so the issue occurs from the justpy side.

However, since 9.3.0 Highcharts Maps has improved geometry https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-maps-v9.3.0, which could have affected another framework's behaviour. I would suggest reaching out JustPy developers directly.

As a workaround, you can try to play around with setting `x`, `y` `dataLabels` positions, e.g:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        x: 15,
        y: -50
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bnejx2kc/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.map.dataLabels.x
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.map.dataLabels.y

Comment: Yeah, I think this is about the justpy's problem not related to the highmap. I should've mentioned that I tried this in the pure high chart and I didn't encounter any problems with it.

Thank you for your work and for letting me know the manual adjustments for x and y. That might be working for now, but it's definitely better to be solved in the justpy itself.